# httpd restart time

Tags: apache

I want to know when the httpd server was restarted, how long it has been up etc.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: your question belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: @daniel probably, but there is a httpd tag here.

Comment: please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get this information is from the httpd.log files, it should show times that httpd was started / stopped assuming that your log files are not being rotated or archived.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user66751 is not totally right.

Assuming centos: service httpd status.

```
root@server2 [~]# service httpd status | grep uptime
   Server uptime: 6 hours 43 minutes 51 seconds
root@server2 [~]#

root@server2 [~]# service httpd status | grep Restart
   Restart Time: Friday, 15-Aug-2014 16:27:04 EDT
root@server2 [~]#
```